# How to make sure no duplications occur when generating numbers from a two-dimensional array in the form of a table

Tags: c#, arrays, random, numbers

Here is a piece of code whereby I generated random numbers ranging to a 100 in the form of a 5x5 table, but I do not know how to make sure no duplicates occur. What should I do in order to make sure duplications do not occur?

```
     int[][] table = new int[5][5];
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {
              int x = (int) (Math.random()*100 + 1);
              table[i][j] = x;
           }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
              System.out.print(table[i][j] + " ");
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
```

I will greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: you can store used numbers and try again if new number is in the list of used ones, or alternatively you could have good unique numbers list and generate number between 0 and list length, then insert good number from position generated and remove it from list which will save you some searching i guess

Comment: I can actually try something like this:

Comment: if(table[z][y]==table[w][u]){
         //do something
         }

Comment: where z,y,w,u are all numbers ranging from 0-5 (the co-ordinates) and do something will change values of the the numbers in each co ordinate if they are == to another number

Answer (score 0):

use a hashmap if possible in form of (number,count)in the form of (key,value) pairs. IF any number has count greater than one then array has duplicate. Best in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will just check what this hashmap is.

Comment: Hashmap is a data structure for keeping track of (key, value) pairs. So for every number as a key you get a value for it which you can assign as 1 and increment each time you get the same value. That will be possible only when you have the same key which means same number in this case and you can find out duplicate case exist or not. If you want I can give you the coed for it

Comment: That would be great! But this hashmap thing is quite good actually for like you said, efficiency...